# If $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|\leq q,\forall n\geq n_0$ Is $|\frac{a_{n_{0}+p}}{a_{n_{0}+(p-1)}}|...|\frac{a_{n_{0}+1}}{a_{n_0}}|\leq q^{p-1}$ or $q^{p}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a trick how to deal with those counting Problems? These kind of problem also occur quite often in combinatorics too. What is the rule of thumb?

Comment: There are simply $p$ terms on the left (look at the indices of the numerators) and each term contributes a $q$ on the right. Why does this question have anything to do with number theory?

Comment: The first index is p and the last is 1. If p is for example 1 I have got 1. That means p Terms establishing the induction base. If the first index is $p+1$ then the second must be p using the inductionhypothesis gives p numbers + 1 for the p+1. Okay I thought since it was a counting Problem I should put it under the numbertheory tag.